# Custom foreign_key in model gives PG::Error column does not exist - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, belongs-to

I have a `VideoCollection` model that will contain many records from another model (called `VideoWork`), using the has_many relationship.  The `VideoCollection` model inherits from the `Collection` model using single table inheritance, while the `VideoWork` model inherits from the `Work` model.

I'm having a problem when I try to call up the video_works that belong to a video_collection.
In my `video_collection#show` action, I use the following to try to display a collection's works:

```
def show
  @video_collection = VideoCollection.find(params[:id])
  @collections = @video_collection.children
  @works = @video_collection.video_works
end
```

But when I try to use @works in the `show` view, I get the following:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column works.video_collection_id does not exist
SELECT "works".* FROM "works"  WHERE "works"."type" IN ('VideoWork') AND "works"."video_collection_id" = $1

##(Error occurs in the line that contains <% @works.each do |work| %>)
```

#### My model files:

```
#----app/models/video_collection.rb----
    class VideoCollection < Collection
      has_many :video_works
    end

#----app/models/video_work.rb----
    class VideoWork < Work
      belongs_to :folder, class_name: "VideoCollection", foreign_key: "folder_id"
    end
```

The "parent" models:

```
#----app/models/collection.rb - (VideoCollection inherits from this)
    class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
    end    

#----app/models/work.rb - (VideoWork inherits from this)
    class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
```

The Schema file:

```
#----db/schema.rb----
    create_table "works", force: true do |t|
      t.string "header"
      t.string "description"
      t.string "type"
      t.string "folder_id"
    end

  create_table "collections", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "ancestry"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "tile_image_link"
end
```

#### My Question

I assume that since I have a `folder_id` column in the `works` table that I should be able to set up the `belongs_to` relationship properly, but it seems that Rails still wants me to have a `video_collection_id` column instead.  I would prefer not use something specific like `video_collection_id` as a foreign key in the `works` table since I need to set up other relationships (e.g.: `photo_collection` has_many `photo_works`, etc).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try putting the `belongs_to association` in the `Work` model itself.

Comment: @Pavan - I moved the entire line `belongs_to :folder, class_name: "VideoCollection", foreign_key: "folder_id"` out of the `VideoWork` model file and into the `Work` file, but I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really use has_many and belongs_to with different foreign keys than the standard, but according to the docs I would do this:

```
class VideoCollection < Collection
  has_many :video_works, foreign_key: "folder_id"
end

class VideoWork < Work
  belongs_to :folder, class_name: "VideoCollection", foreign_key: "folder_id"
end
```

Your Pg error says that the association is looking for 'video_collection_id' instead of 'folder_id'

[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) (chapter 4.3.2.5)